# Get current TR index for Adding / removing TR elements to DOM and keep reference in sync

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, indexing, focus

I have a html page where `input` fields can be added an removed. Added by hitting key *"Enter"* on the last `input` field and removing by hitting key combination *"CTRL+Backspace"* in an `input` field.

This works fine if I just add or delete the last `input` field. **If I start to remove an `input` field in the middle it does not work.** It does not work, because I identify the last line by the *id-attribute* of the last `tr` and if I remove a `input` field in the middle the concept does not work anymore.

As current solution, I want to know the index of the active `tr`, so that I do not have to relay on my *id-attributes*. With current `tr` I mean the input field which has the focus. **But here I struggle, I can only access the current position with *id-attribute*.**

```js
// get id from active element
activeElementID = $( position ).attr( 'id' );
```

I tried to get the index, but there I do not get anything back, its alwas index 0:

```js
// get id from active element
activeElementID = $( position ).attr( 'id' );

aEl = $( position ).parent(  ).index(  );
console.log( "INDEX: " + aEl );

// output on every input field: "INDEX: 0"
```

**How can I identify the current `tr` index, and do stuff with it, e.g. remove the current `tr`?**

**Important**: each `tr` line is bound to an object in an array (in my code called Dom), the index of the `tr` and the index of the array shall be the same so that I know which line belongs to which element in the array. The array will store content which I need in the `tr`/`input` fields.

**I am open as well for other solutions, to have rows which can be added and removed with the described behaviour, and the rows should be coupled to an object which I can access and store additional information**

Here is my current solution, where I need to know how I can identify the current `tr` index:

```js
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

    <title>Row test</title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    // global function 

    // zeilen ID: zeileX, withouth #
    function zeilenID( id ) { 
        return "zeile" + id;
    }

    // css zeilen ID: #zeileX
    function zID( id ) { 
        return "#" + zeilenID( id );
    }

    function inputID( id ) { 
        return "input" + id;
    }

    function iID( id ) { 
        return "#" + inputID( id );
    }

    // array that holds the line. 
    // lastline is the lineID of the last line
    Dom = function(  ) { };
    Dom.prototype.dom = new Array();
    // Dom.prototype.lastline = "not set";

    // new object to hold the data in the Dom
    Line = function(  ) {  };
    Line.prototype.variable = "var-name";

    // obj, should be a foo Dom object
    function addRow( obj ) { 
        nLine = foo.dom.length; // size of array 2
        obj.dom.push( new Line ); // new size of array 3. Thats why nLine must come before!!!

        $( "#lines tr:last" ).after( "<tr><td id='"+ zeilenID( nLine ) +"'><input type='text' id='" + inputID( nLine ) + "' value='" + nLine + "'></input></td></tr>" );
        //foo.lastline = nLine; // inputID( key );

        $( iID( nLine ) ).focus(  );
    }

    function rmRow( obj, id ) { 
        obj.dom.splice( id, 1 );
    }

    $(document).ready(function(){

        // create a new Dom call foo
        foo = new Dom(  );

        console.log( "count: " + foo.dom.length );

        // add a new array element
        foo.dom.push( new Line );

        // create a new Line called linie
        linie = new Line(  );

        // change the content of variable
        linie.variable = "platzhalter";
        foo.dom.push( linie );

        $.each( foo.dom, function( key, val ) { 
            console.log( key );
            for( kex in val ) { 
                console.log( "> " + kex + ": " + val[kex] );
            }
            $( "#lines tr:last" ).after( "<tr><td id='"+ zeilenID( key ) +"'><input type='text' id='" + inputID( key ) + "' value='" + val['variable'] + "'></input></td></tr>" );
            // foo.lastline = key; // inputID( key );
        } );

    });

    $(document).keypress(function(e) {
        if(e.which == 13) {
            // alert('You pressed enter!');

            // get active element
            position = document.activeElement;

            // get id from active element
            activeElementID = $( position ).attr( 'id' );

                    aEl = $( position ).parent(  ).index(  );
                    console.log( "INDEX: " + aEl );

            console.log( "focus element id: " + activeElementID );
            console.log( "last count: " + foo.dom.length );

            lastline = inputID( foo.dom.length - 1 );

            amountOfRows = $( "#lines tr" ).length - 1; // as we have one tr more, the heading

            if ( activeElementID == lastline ) {  
                addRow( foo );
            }

        }

        // CTRL + Backspace
        if (e.ctrlKey) { // CTRL
            if ( e.which == 8 ) {  // Backspace

                console.log( "BACKSPACE.... with CTRL" );
                position = document.activeElement;

                // get id from active element
                activeElementID = $( position ).attr( 'id' );
                activeNum = activeElementID.substr( -1 );

                $( zID( activeNum ) ).remove(  );
                rmRow( foo, activeNum );
                console.log( "removed row: " + activeNum );

                $( iID( activeNum - 1 ) ).focus(  );
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: downvote without explanation of reason is unfair behaviour: -1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out, with `parent()`, `prop()` and `rowIndex`.

```js
aEl = $( position ).parent(  ).parent(  ).prop( 'rowIndex' ) - 1; 
console.log( "INDEX: " + aEl );
```